Series $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\sqrt{\binom{2n}{n}}\ \frac{x^n}{\sqrt[3]{n+1}}$
Check if the series $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\sqrt{\binom{2n}{n}}\ \frac{x^n}{\sqrt[3]{n+1}}$$ converges.
I found that the ratio $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\sqrt{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}\ \frac{x^{n+1}}{\sqrt[3]{n+2}}}{\sqrt{\binom{2n}{n}}\ \frac{x^n}{\sqrt[3]{n+1}}}\\=\sqrt{\frac{\frac{\left(2n+2\right)!}{\left(n+1\right)!\left(n+1\right)!}}{\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{n!n!}}}\sqrt[3]{\frac{n+1}{n+2}}x=\sqrt{\frac{\left(2n+1\right)\left(2n+2\right)}{\left(n+1\right)^2}}\sqrt[3]{\frac{n+1}{n+2}}x$$
Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=|x|\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{\dfrac{4n^2+\dots}{n^2+\ldots}}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{n+1}{n+2}}=2|x|,$$ so the radius of convergence is $R=\dfrac12$.
So we have to check the series when $x=\frac12$, so $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\sqrt{\binom{2n}{n}}\ \frac{1}{2^n\sqrt[3]{n+1}}$$
Let's try to find the limit $$\lim _{n\to \infty }n\left(\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}-1\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty }n\left(2\sqrt{\frac{\left(n+1\right)^2}{\left(2n+1\right)\left(2n+2\right)}}\sqrt[3]{\frac{n+2}{n+1}}-1\right)\\=\lim _{n\to \infty }n\left[2\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{2\left(2n+1\right)}}\sqrt[3]{\frac{n+2}{n+1}}-1\right]=\lim _{n\to \infty }n\left[2\sqrt[6]{\frac{\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)^2}{8\left(2n+1\right)^3}}-1\right]\\=\lim _{n\to \infty }n\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt[6]{8}}\sqrt[6]{\frac{8\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)^2}{8\left(2n+1\right)^3}}-1\right)\\=\lim _{n\to \infty }n\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt[6]{8.8}}\sqrt[6]{\frac{8\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)^2}{\left(2n+1\right)^3}}-1\right)$$
Let me denote $$f(n)=\frac{8\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)^2}{\left(2n+1\right)^3}$$ Then $f(n)-1$ is $$f(n)-1=\frac{28n^2+58n+31}{\left(2n+1\right)^3},$$ so $$\left(1+\frac{28n^2+58n+31}{\left(2n+1\right)^3}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}=1+\frac{28n^2+58n+31}{6\left(2n+3\right)^3}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right),$$ and the limit is $$\lim _{n\to \infty }n.\frac{28n^2+58n+31}{6\left(2n+1\right)^3}=\frac{28}{48}=\frac{7}{12},$$ but in the authors' solution it says that the limit is $\dfrac{5}{6}$. Do I have a mistake?

What is $b_n$ in your solution? Is it $a_n(\frac12)$? There’s a typo, probably, $2$ missing.

@Aig, what is missing? I thought it would be good idea to use another symbol, as $b_n$ is the common term when we put $x=\dfrac12$ into $a_n$. Where is a 2 missing?

@Aig, fixed the typo, sorry!

Right after $b_n$ appears. The missing $2$ appears later though. Also later in the text $2n+1$ briefly becomes $2n+3$. It’s all just typos. But what I don’t understand in your solution, is how you deal with $f(n)$ but never use the coefficient $\frac2{\sqrt[6]{8\cdot8}}$.

@Aig, well, that coefficient is $1$, so what do you mean? Thanks for the typos! I fixed them.

Disregard a comment about $f(n)$, the limit is indeed $\frac7{12}$. I also took a liberty to correct another small typo in your post.

It seems there is some minor typos like this one
$$\ldots=\lim _{n\to \infty }n\left[2\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{2\left(2n+1\right)}}\sqrt[3]{\frac{n+2}{n+1}}-1\right]=\lim _{n\to \infty }n\left[2\sqrt[6]{\frac{\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)^2}{8\color{red}{\left(2n+1\right)^3}}}-1\right]=\ldots$$
but this latter limit seems correct to me and it gives $\frac{7}{12}$ as result.

$2n+3$ becomes $2n+1$ back in the very next expression.

@Aig Yes indeed these are minor typos, the final limit seems correct to my check and also the evaluation for the limit.

Thank you for the found typo! I fixed it. Thanks!
